# Mobile automation code is not running and giving an error related to allure

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, android-uiautomator, allure

I am writing mobile automation test scripts for the first time using Appium. I am trying to run an app that is installed on an android phone that is connected to the computer. I have written the code in Java on Eclipse. My code is not running and I am seeing the following message on the console:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.9.10
[TestNG] Running:
N:\eclipse-workspace\TestPro\testng.xml

[main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not stop test container: container with uuid 67e81eee-0a3a-489a-9b83-5f5e3305f573 not found
[main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not write test container: container with uuid 67e81eee-0a3a-489a-9b83-5f5e3305f573 not found

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

This is how I set up the desired capabilities -

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup()
{
    try
    {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        
        
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "R8KN800EJ0J");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.jayway.contacts");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.jayway.contacts.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        caps.setCapability("fullReset", false);
        caps.setCapability("noReset", true);
        
        URL url = new URL("http://127/0/0/1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, caps);
    }
    
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        System.out.println("Cause: " +exp.getCause());
        System.out.println("Message: " +exp.getMessage());
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding allure dependency on my **pom.xml** file, and importing allure headers on my class file but I still got the same error. I have no idea what allure is and how it works, and I haven't used it on my code but am still getting the error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reasons behind the error.

1. I was using the allure dependency on my list of dependencies in the pom.xml file
2. I forgot to add the class that I intended to run in the testng.xml file

Once I fixed the issues mentioned above, the code successfully ran.